# Incremental number for certain tags in XML Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, xml

I have an XML file with following data

```
<Shipment>
 <ShipmentReference>1453464536</ShipmentReference>
 <ShipmentCode>2020IE</ShipmentCode>
</Shipment>
<Shipment>
 <ShipmentReference>7896535784</ShipmentReference>
 <ShipmentCode>2020IE</ShipmentCode>
</Shipment>
<Shipment>
 <ShipmentReference>5674321985</ShipmentReference>
 <ShipmentCode>2020IE</ShipmentCode>
</Shipment>
```

I want to know if it is possible to edit only  tag with incremental number value, something like below

```
<Shipment>
 <ShipmentReference>9999999001</ShipmentReference>
 <ShipmentCode>2020IE</ShipmentCode>
</Shipment>
<Shipment>
 <ShipmentReference>9999999002</ShipmentReference>
 <ShipmentCode>2020IE</ShipmentCode>
</Shipment>
<Shipment>
 <ShipmentReference>9999999003</ShipmentReference>
 <ShipmentCode>2020IE</ShipmentCode>
</Shipment>
```

I'm not sure if we can use Column Editor

Appreciate any help

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using a script here. Install the Notepad++ **Python Script** plugin and run the Python script below:

```py
# ------------------------------------
# https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15318/replace-text-with-incremented-counter
# Thanks to Scott Sumner for portions of this code 
# ------------------------------------
count = 9999999000

def calculate(m):
    global count
    count += 1
    return '<ShipmentReference>' + str(count) + '</ShipmentReference>'

editor.rereplace('<ShipmentReference>([0-9]+)</ShipmentReference>', calculate);
```

[image]